# How to solve duplicate identifier problem in Typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio

When I try to assign a value in an object from another module class it shows duplicate identifier and subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property `office` must be of type `Office`, but here has type `any`. I have tried many searches to understand but I am totally screwed.

That's the module class

```
export class Office 
{
public Name: string = "";
GetLocation(): void
   {
    alert("Santosh");
   }
}
```

And here is import class in another module

```
import { Office } from "./Office";

       class Student
      {
        public office: Office = new Office();
        office.Name="MBSTU";// error duplicate  identifier

        Name: string = "Talukder";
        Roll: number = 10;
       Address: any = "Tangail";
      }
```

I am using visual studio 2019 and typescript version 3.9.6.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rickz, let me know how to solve it

Comment: You can't write `office.Name="MBSTU";` in the class body, it has to be either in the constructor or a function/method.

Comment: You saved my life!! it seems to ridiculous but it maked me hessel! Thanks.